# How can I extract a string from a text field that matches with a "value" in my Dictionary and return the dict's key into a new column in the Output?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I would like to extract from a description field (column in my DF) the first string that matches another string in a dictionary (using Python) or show Null if there is no match, for i.e.:

```
# read an excel with columns (IDX, DESCRIPTION)
df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
```

Input: example.xlsx

```
[IDX] [Column DESCRIPTION]
[Row 1] ["I live in Russia"]
[Row 2] ["I was borned in USA"]
[Row 3] ["I would like to move to England"]
```

My dictionary has the following countries:

```
countries= [
  {'value': ['usa'], 'country': 'United States of America'},
  {'value': ['u.s.a.'], 'country': 'United States of America'},
  {'value': ['united states'], 'country': 'United States of America'},
  {'value': ['spain'], 'country': 'Spain'},
  {'value': ['russia'], 'country': 'Russia'},
  {'value': ['rusia'], 'country': 'Russia'}, 
  {'value': ['canada'], 'country': 'Canada'},
  {'value': ['france'], 'country': 'France'},
  {'value': ['mexico'], 'country': 'Mexico'}
]
```

Output:

```
[IDX] [Column DESCRIPTION] [Column Country]
[Row 1] ["I live in Russia"] ['RUSSIA']
[Row 2] ["I was borned in USA"] ['UNITED STATES OF AMERICA']
[Row 3] ["I would like to move to England"] [Null]
```

A new excel with an additional column with the matched country or null

Comment: Please format your question properly. Nothing makes sense here. That's not a dictionary either.

Comment: Why the output is like this? What's the logic?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want something like this:

```
strngs = ["I live in Russia", "I was borned in USA", "I would like to move to England"]

dictt = ["USA", "CANADA", "RUSSIA", "MEXICO"]

for strng in strngs:
    matched = False
    for key in dictt:
        if key in strng.upper():
            print key
            matched = True

    if not matched:
        print "Null"
```

I hope, it helps you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just updated the question in order to be more accurate! Thanks again.